# Sorted key value lambda not working

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I've got a list comprehension that isn't sorting once I add the 'not in stop' method. Basically, the sorting function I had before is lost now when I include stopwords for this NLTK. Can anyone point out what I did wrong?

I have now included everything in the code for better reference.

EDITED:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string

stop = stopwords.words('english') + list(string.punctuation)
f = open('review_text_all.txt', encoding="utf-8")
raw = f.read().lower().replace("'", "").replace("\\", "").replace(",", 
"").replace("\ufeff", "")

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)

bgs = nltk.bigrams(tokens)

fdist = nltk.FreqDist(bgs)
for (k,v) in sorted(fdist.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1] not in stop), 
reverse=True):
    print(k,v)
```

Here is my result w/'not in stop'

```
('or', 'irish') 3
('put', 'one') 1
('was', 'repealed') 1
('please', '?') 6
('contact', 'your') 2
('wear', 'sweats') 1
```

without 'not in stop'

```
('white', 'people') 4362
('.', 'i') 3734
('in', 'the') 2880
('of', 'the') 2634
('to', 'be') 2217
('all', 'white') 1778
```

as you can see the sorted works, but only once I remove the 'not in stop'

Comment: what is `fdist` and what is your desired sorted output? Include minimal examples

Comment: Please post your input and desired output.

Comment: do you want to sort or to filter the list ? Because sorting on a boolean criteria will almost certainly not produce what you expect.

Comment: Perhaps you need to first apply the filter function, and then sort. As already written, your function for sorting is incorrect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `key` parameter of [the sorted method](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sorted) is a function that will let you tell python on which key (attribute/value related to the item of the list) to sort.

In your case, your function will return True or False.... which are not really good values to make a sort :)

EDIT:

from what I understand of what you want to achieve, you need to add before (or after) the sort a [filter method](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#filter) that will remove from your list the items which are in your "stop words" list.

Something like this :

```
for (k,v) in sorted(filter(lambda x: (x[1] not in stop), fdist.items()), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    print(k,v)
```

Comment: It worked, but not exactly the way I needed it to. It sorted by the keys, but I actually need the values to be sorted from highest to lowest.

Comment: @M4cJunk13 I updated my answer with the (I think) correct comparison method (bvased on the apparition frequency of  the words)

Comment: Perfect, it worked!!! Thank you so much. I'm still trying to get a better understanding at using lambdas.